# How to get item by id in firebase?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I'm trying to get an item by its id.

Following the firebase documentation, I adapted my code as follows:

Service:

```
getItem: function(id) {
        var data = $firebaseObject(ref.child('products').child(id));
        return data;
}
```

Controller:

```
function get() {
      console.log(id);
      vm.product = Product.getItem(id);
      console.log(vm.product);
}
```

In my console.log I get this:

[image]

EDIT:

Searching, I edited my service the following way

```
getParking: function(id) {
            var list = $firebaseArray(ref);
            list.$loaded(function(data) {
            console.log(data === list);
            }, function(error) {
                console.log("error", error);
            })
            var rec = list.$getRecord(id);
            console.log(rec);
        }
```

But the result of console.log (rec) is null

EDIT 2:

```
list.$loaded().then(function() {
            console.log('done');
            var rec = list.$getRecord(id);
            console.log(rec);
        })
```

But how can I call this "rec" in my controller?

Comment: ref.push().key;

Comment: snapshot.name() (deprecated)

Comment: var key =snapshot.key;

Comment: Sorry, I'm noob on firebase. Could you give me an example?

Comment: It will help. https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray-addnewdata

Comment: whats your firebase data url?

Comment: var ref = firebase.database().ref('products'); I believe that firebase.database () accesses the var config = {database: ""} declared in the index

Comment: do you have a line in your code like this? var ref = new Firebase("url in here"); i need url

Comment: In my index.html I have this: <script>
      // Initialize Firebase
      var config = {
        apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        authDomain: "xxxxxxxxx.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://xxxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com",
        storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxx.appspot.com"
      };
      firebase.initializeApp(config);
    </script>

Comment: databaseURL: "https://teste-a29dc.firebaseio.com",